# Inserting array values into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to find another question with the answer to this but I've had no luck.  My question is basically...will this work?

```
$insert_tweets = "INSERT INTO tweets (
  'id',
  'created_at',
  'from_user_id',
  'profile_image',
  'from_user',
  'from_user_name',
  'text' 
  ) VALUES (
  {$user_data[$i]["id"]},
  {$user_data[$i]["created_at"]},
  {$user_data[$i]["from_user_id"]},
  {$user_data[$i]["profile_image"]},
  {$user_data[$i]["from_user"]},
  {$user_data[$i]["from_user_name"]},
  {$user_data[$i]["text"]}
)"

        for($i=0;$i<count($user_data);$i++){
            mysqli_query($mysqli,$insert_tweets);
        }
```

$user_data is a multi-dimensional array, the first level of which is numeric, the subsequent level is associative.

Also, what would be the best way to "database prepare"/sanitize the associative array variables prior to insertion?  I don't anticipate any malicious data but it is always possible.

Comment: Yes it will work if you fix the syntax error, missing `;` at the end of the SQL _and_ move the sql string inside your for loop. string after `)"`

Comment: you don't need the single quotes around the column names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        for($i=0;$i<count($user_data);$i++){
            $insert_tweets = "INSERT INTO tweets ('id','created_at','from_user_id','profile_image','from_user','from_user_name','text') VALUES ({$user_data[$i]["id"]},{$user_data[$i]["created_at"]},{$user_data[$i]["from_user_id"]},{$user_data[$i]["profile_image"]},{$user_data[$i]["from_user"]},{$user_data[$i]["from_user_name"]},{$user_data[$i]["text"]})";
            mysqli_query($mysqli,$insert_tweets);
        }
```

This should work

Comment: Oh gees, what a stupid error.  Thanks for catching that.  In short, the SQL statement looks okay though?

Comment: Hey Try this and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will work, but the best way to do this would be to use PDO.

You can create nameless parameters in your prepare statement and then just pass in a array to bind values to those params.

```
$data = array('val1', 'val2');
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (? , ?)");
$query->execute($data);
```

PDO will escape the input values for you.

Here's a tutorial on PDO to get you started
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion on sanitizing your array:

What i do is create a basic function for sanitizing data:

```
function array_sanitize(&$item){
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}
```

Then you can use the `array_walk()` to sanitize your array with your new function. ([php manual refrence](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php))

and sanitize by passing in your array like this:

```
array_walk($user_data, 'array_sanitize');
```